# How does one change methods of an iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

Hey guys, I am fairly new to Java, and I have a question about collections and iterators.

In my code I have a collection (which somewhere down the road extends extends Iterable) and every object is basically a LinkedList.
I need an iterator for that collection, so I've wrote it down this way:

```
public class A{

     LinkedList<B> BList= new LinkedList<B>();

    ...

    public Iterator<B> iterator() {
        return BList.iterator();
    }
}
```

Now, the question is, how can I change any method of that iterator?
Or to be more specific, how can I disable the remove method of the iterator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an unmodifiable list, use the other answer posted here. But if you want to disable **only** the remove, a possible way is to create a new class that extends the Iterator interface but whose remove() method throws an exception (or simply does nothing) and forwards every other method to the original iterator object:

```
public class MyIterator implements Iterator {
    private Iterator wrappedIterator;

    public MyIterator( Iterator it ) {
        wrappedIterator = it;
    }

    public void remove( blabla ) {
        //do nothing or raise an error, whatever floats your boat
    }

    public void otherIteratorMethod() {
        wrappedIterator.otherIteratorMethod();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I guess I was expected to do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You could return an iterator of an unmodifiable list:

```
import java.util.Collections;

...

public class A{

    LinkedList<B> BList= new LinkedList<B>();

    ...

    public Iterator<B> iterator() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(BList).iterator();
    }
}
```

This will wrap your List with an implementation that disallows any changes to the list structure (like removal).  You then return an iterator based on the wrapped list.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks very "tricky", is that the only way?

The reason I am asking is because it's basically a home assignment, and I don't think they were counting on us knowing about the unmodifiablelist.

There is no way to change it besides relying on already existing iterators?

Thanks again!